# Cannot start Xampp Apache service

Tags: apache, xampp

I need Apache and MySQL services for my project but I cannot start the apache service.

Here is the log:

```
5:45:22 PM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
5:45:22 PM  [main]  Windows Version: Windows 8  64-bit
5:45:22 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 5.6.12
5:45:22 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.1  [ Compiled: May 7th 2013 ]
5:45:22 PM  [main]  You are not running with administrator rights! This will work for
5:45:22 PM  [main]  most application stuff but whenever you do something with services
5:45:22 PM  [main]  there will be a security dialogue or things will break! So think 
5:45:22 PM  [main]  about running this application with administrator rights!
5:45:22 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
5:45:22 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
5:45:23 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
5:45:23 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
5:45:23 PM  [main]  Enabling autostart for module "Apache"
5:45:23 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
5:45:23 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
5:45:23 PM  [Apache]    Autostart active: starting...
5:45:23 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache service...
5:45:25 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
5:45:27 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
5:45:27 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
5:45:27 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
5:45:27 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
5:45:27 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
5:45:27 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
5:45:27 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
5:45:27 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

First when I installed Xampp I wasn't able to run Apache service. Then I unchecked "Use port 80 and 443" in Skype and signed out of Skype and changed ports in the confg files from 80 to 8080 and 443 to 4433. After doing this the Apache server worked smoothly. But after restarting my laptop, Xampp showed that Apache service has started but it didn't start actually. And then I upgraded to Windows 10 and now this is happening.

PS It's my first question

Comment: You've nearly answered the question yourself. If it was running smoothly before all this, then there's a great chance it's a port issue. But then, what have you checked in that area: are there any other services running on port 80 ? have you two Xampps running ? And when did the problem start ? Before or after the Windows 10 upgrade ?

Comment: Are you able to reinstall XAMPP, or have you already created some databases in MySQL?

Comment: Let me try reinstalling Xampp once again. I'm using port 8080 for Apache. And I've not created any databases till now.

Comment: Well, reinstalling fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Reinstalling XAMPP and changing ports for apache from 80 to 8080 and from 443 to 4443.

For port 80 edit httpd.conf file

For port 443 edit http-ssl.conf file